# Discovering the set of all frequent sequences

Tags: python, r

I need to find the set of all frequent sequences of events happened.
The data consists of two columns i.e. date with time stamp and the events.
I need help to find out the frequent set of events occurring for examining the behavior of the user.
Below is the sample data

```
    date     events
6/1/17 7:25     A
6/1/17 7:33     B
6/1/17 7:33     C
6/1/17 7:33     D
6/1/17 7:33     Z
6/1/17 7:33     C
6/1/17 7:33     G
6/1/17 7:34     H
6/1/17 7:34     J
6/1/17 7:34     K
6/1/17 7:34     A
6/1/17 7:34     B
6/1/17 7:34     C
6/1/17 7:34     D
6/1/17 7:34     F
6/1/17 7:35     G
6/1/17 7:35     J
6/1/17 7:35     Y
6/1/17 7:35     D
6/1/17 7:35     A
6/1/17 7:35     B
6/1/17 7:35     C
6/1/17 7:35     D
```

As you can see in the data the event 'ABCD' is the most common occurring sequence. I need an output saying 'ABCD' set of events has occurred 3 times.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are patterns which are used by you restricted to some length? For instance why are you saying ABCD is most used pattern not for instance "AB" or "A".

Comment: Does a sequence always have 4 events?

Comment: Depending on how and if the length of the sequences is restricted, the *Apriori* or *SPADE* algorithm might be of help here. You just need to get the data into the right format. See packages `arules` and `arulesSequences`.

Comment: No there is no specific bin length

Comment: Hi @VikramJois looks like a lot of good answers below. Please consider accepting one by clicking on the check mark to the left of the answer. This lets the community know that the answer was helpful in solving your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can create a function to create all the letter combinations based on a bin length. After that, use `table` to count the number and return the word with the maximum count. The advantage of this approach is users can change the bin length, such as 3 or 2, depends on their goals.

```
# Create the vector
events <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "Z", "C", "G", "H", 
            "J", "K", "A", "B", "C", "D", "F", "G",
            "J", "Y", "D", "A", "B", "C", "D")


# Design a function to group letters based on a bin size
bin_fun <- function(vec, bin){
  iter <- length(events) - bin + 1
  result <- character()
  for (i in 1:iter){
   vec2 <- vec[i:(i + bin - 1)]
   word <- paste(vec2, collapse = "")
   result <- c(result, word)
  }
  return(result)
}

# Apply the bin_fun to events and bin = 4
result <- bin_fun(events, 4)

# Count number of each word
table(result)
result
ABCD BCDF BCDZ CDFG CDZC CGHJ DABC DFGJ DZCG FGJY GHJK GJYD HJKA JKAB JYDA KABC YDAB ZCGH 
   3    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1

# Return the word with maximum count
table(result)[which.max(table(result))]
ABCD 
   3
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, it really helped me a lot

Comment: The bin function is not static in the above condition, when I change the bin size it is acting as the minimum bin size and the max bin size is varying

Comment: I think its working fine, I got confused as the collapse was not set with any special character

Comment: as I am getting multiple single occurrence sequences,how can I eliminate sequences with only one count ?

Comment: Try this `table(result)[table(result) != 1]`

Answer (score 4):

Note that A, B, AB, BC, CD, ABC and BCD occur just as frequently as ABCD and C and D each occur more frequently so we will reinterpret the question as finding for each sequence length k > 1 (up to 9) the most frequently occurring sequences.  Below `Lall[[i]]` gives all length i+1 sequences and the following line reduces that to those having the maximum frequency for that sequence length.  Further below we reduce that to those sequences that are not subsequences of other sequences on the list.

```
library(zoo)

k <- 2:9
Lall <- setNames(lapply(k, function(i) table(rollapply(event, width = i, toString))), k)
L <- Filter(length, lapply(Lall, function(x) x[x == max(x) & x > 1]))
```

giving:

```
$`2`

A, B B, C C, D 
   3    3    3 

$`3`

A, B, C B, C, D 
      3       3 

$`4`
A, B, C, D 
         3
```

We could optionally reduce this further to those sequences that are not subsequences of another sequences unless they have higher frequency:

```
vec <- unlist(unname(L))
nms <- names(vec)
is_le <- function(i) any(grepl(nms[i], tail(nms, -i)) & (vec[i] <= tail(vec, -i)))
vec[ ! sapply(seq_along(nms), is_le) ]
```

giving:

```
A, B, C, D 
         3
```

**Note:** We used this input:

```
Lines <- "date     events
6/1/17 7:25     A
6/1/17 7:33     B
6/1/17 7:33     C
6/1/17 7:33     D
6/1/17 7:33     Z
6/1/17 7:33     C
6/1/17 7:33     G
6/1/17 7:34     H
6/1/17 7:34     J
6/1/17 7:34     K
6/1/17 7:34     A
6/1/17 7:34     B
6/1/17 7:34     C
6/1/17 7:34     D
6/1/17 7:34     F
6/1/17 7:35     G
6/1/17 7:35     J
6/1/17 7:35     Y
6/1/17 7:35     D
6/1/17 7:35     A
6/1/17 7:35     B
6/1/17 7:35     C
6/1/17 7:35     D"

DF <- read.table(text = Lines, skip = 1, as.is = TRUE, 
    col.names = c("Date", "Time", "event"))
event <- DF$event
```

**Update:**   Show how to reduce L to those sequences that are not subsequences of other sequences in L unless they have higher frequency.

Answer (score 1):

#### Your data

```
df <- structure(list(date = c("6/1/17 7:25", "6/1/17 7:33", "6/1/17 7:33", 
"6/1/17 7:33", "6/1/17 7:33", "6/1/17 7:33", "6/1/17 7:33", "6/1/17 7:34", 
"6/1/17 7:34", "6/1/17 7:34", "6/1/17 7:34", "6/1/17 7:34", "6/1/17 7:34", 
"6/1/17 7:34", "6/1/17 7:34", "6/1/17 7:35", "6/1/17 7:35", "6/1/17 7:35", 
"6/1/17 7:35", "6/1/17 7:35", "6/1/17 7:35", "6/1/17 7:35", "6/1/17 7:35"
), events = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "Z", "C", "G", "H", "J", "K", 
"A", "B", "C", "D", "F", "G", "J", "Y", "D", "A", "B", "C", "D"
)), .Names = c("date", "events"), row.names = c(NA, -23L), class = 
c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x0000000014320788>)
```

#### Solution

Save all *N*-mers (*N* = 1:nrow(df)) into a list `L`, then `Reduce` the list into a vector and use `table` to count the occurrence of each *N*-mer, then save table entries with the max value.

```
L <- lapply(nrow(df):1, function(x) sapply(1:(nrow(df)-(x-1)), function(y) paste0(df$events[y:(y+(x-1))], collapse="")))
T <- table(Reduce(c, L))
M <- T[T==max(T)]
```

#### Output

```
C D 
4 4
```

#### N-mers > 1

If you want to save only *N*-mers > 1, then discard *N*-mers with length 1, and sort the table by descending `nchar`

```
cM <- T[T==max(T[nchar(names(T))>1])]
val <- cM[sort(nchar(names(cM)), decreasing=TRUE)]
```

#### Alt output

```
ABCD  ABC  ABC   AB   AB   AB    A    A 
   3    3    3    3    3    3    3    3
```

You can save the top entry with

```
head(val,1)
# ABCD
#    3
```

Or with ties

```
val[nchar(names(val))==max(nchar(names(val)))]
# ABCD
#    3
```

Answer (score 0):

I put your data into an csv.

Searching for the sequence which occurs most often (I used R):

```
    data = read.table(file = "path/to/csv", header = T, sep = ";")
    data$events = as.character(data$events)
    finalSequences = NULL
    for(i in 1:nrow(data)) {
      if(any(is.na(data[i:(i+3),2]))){
        stop()
      }
      sequence = paste(data[i:(i+3),2], collapse = "")
      finalSequences = c(finalSequences, sequence)
    }
    table(finalSequences)
```

**Edited**

I edited my answer just to fulfill the requirements of the OP. Just to be clear, it is nearly the same as @ycw already pointed out.

Comment: I don't think that's what's intended. The post states to find "the set of all frequent sequences of events happened". Yours is only looking for "ABCD".

Comment: I think the question is a bit unclear. I interpreted, that he just want to know this particular sequence.

Comment: I thought we need to find out which combination is the most frequent one, then determine the number of occurrences.

Comment: Yes, I need to find out which combination is the most frequent one, then determine the number of occurrences.